# Installing Gtk2 on portable strawberry

Tags: windows, perl, gtk, strawberry-perl

I downloaded "strawberry-perl-5.12.2.0-portable" and "gtk+-bundle_2.22.1-20101227_win32". I extracted strawberry-perl in some directory and there I put gtk folder with gtk stuff.

In portableshell.bat I changed Path env and added: "%drivep%\gtk\bin;%drivep%\gtk\lib;". Don't ask me why I added lib directory, I saw that some guy added it in some website.

When I run in portableshell command: "pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0" I get:

```
c:\test>pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0
-mms-bitfields -Ic:/test/gtk/include/gtk-2.0 -Ic:/test/gtk/lib/gtk-2.0/include -
Ic:/test/gtk/include/atk-1.0 -Ic:/test/gtk/include/cairo -Ic:/test/gtk/include/g
dk-pixbuf-2.0 -Ic:/test/gtk/include/pango-1.0 -Ic:/test/gtk/include/glib-2.0 -Ic
:/test/gtk/lib/glib-2.0/include -Ic:/test/gtk/include -Ic:/test/gtk/include/free
type2 -Ic:/test/gtk/include/libpng14  -Lc:/test/gtk/lib -lgtk-win32-2.0 -lgdk-wi
n32-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixb
uf-2.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0
-lintl
```

All folders looks fine, I also have complete log of compiling glib [here](https://gist.github.com/872179). It looks like it doesn't compile because pkg-config gives bad data, or something.

Does anyone have some idea how to make this thing work?

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on compilation, see http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=793472 for "build-gtk-glib-post.PL" , it worked for me ( be sure to use the download link  )

Alternatively, use

```
ppm install Bundle::Gnome2
```

Its available from both the ActiveState and trouchelle repositories ( see http://kobesearch.cpan.org/dist/Bundle-Gnome2 )

Comment: well script is buggy, but I'll try to extract knowledge from it and then compile.

Comment: XoR: if you get a good solution for Strawberry, please publish it in Strawberry mailing list and http://win32.perl.org.

Comment: Can you use `ppm`s in Strawberry Perl now?  How is that even possible?  Activestate uses a MS compiler and Strawberry Perl uses gcc.