# Which version of Perl do I have?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to find out which Perl version my [Camelbox](http://code.google.com/p/camelbox/) Perl is running, because I want the same version of [Strawberry Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strawberry_Perl). Strawberry Perl comes in 5.10.0.0 to 5.10.0.6. Which one do I have?

```
C:\camelbox\bin> perl -v | perl -ne "print if $.==2"
This is perl, v5.10.0 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread

C:\camelbox\bin> perl -E "say $]"
5.010000
```

Edit:

```
C:\camelbox\bin>perl -V
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 10 subversion 0) configuration:
  Platform:
    osname=MSWin32, osvers=5.1, archname=MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
    uname=''
    config_args='undef'
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=undef
    useithreads=define, usemultiplicity=define
    useperlio=define, d_sfio=undef, uselargefiles=define, usesocks=undef
    use64bitint=undef, use64bitall=undef, uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='gcc', ccflags =' -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DHAVE_DES_FCRYPT  -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -fno-strict-aliasing -DPERL_MSVCRT_READFIX',
    optimize='-s -O2',
    cppflags='-DWIN32'
    ccversion='', gccversion='3.4.5', gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4, longsize=4, ptrsize=4, doublesize=8, byteorder=1234
    d_longlong=undef, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=12
    ivtype='long', ivsize=4, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='long long', lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=8, prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='g++', ldflags ='-s -L"C:\camelbox\lib\CORE" -L"C:\camelbox\lib"'
    libpth=C:\camelbox\lib
    libs=-lmsvcrt -lmoldname -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -lnetapi32 -luuid -lws2_32 -lmpr -lwinmm -lversion -lodbc32 -lodbccp32
    perllibs=-lmsvcrt -lmoldname -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -lnetapi32 -luuid -lws2_32 -lmpr -lwinmm -lversion -lodbc32 -lodbccp32
    libc=-lmsvcrt, so=dll, useshrplib=true, libperl=libperl510.a
    gnulibc_version=''
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_win32.xs, dlext=dll, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags=' '
    cccdlflags=' ', lddlflags='-mdll -s -L"C:\camelbox\lib\CORE" -L"C:\camelbox\lib"'


    Characteristics of this binary (from libperl):
      Compile-time options: MULTIPLICITY PERL_DONT_CREATE_GVSV
                            PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT PERL_IMPLICIT_SYS
                            PERL_MALLOC_WRAP PL_OP_SLAB_ALLOC USE_ITHREADS
                            USE_LARGE_FILES USE_PERLIO
      Built under MSWin32
      Compiled at Apr 22 2009 11:23:56
      @INC:
        C:/camelbox/lib
        C:/camelbox/site/lib
        .
```

Comment: That indicates you're running 5.10.0, but there's not enough information to determine what flavor of Perl you're running, if it's Strawberry or ActiveState or whatever.  They should all run the same, but we'd need to see the full `perl -V` (note: capital V) to know.

Comment: @schwern: I've appended `perl -V` output now.

Comment: Ok, that's the Camelbox Perl 5.10.0.  You want the equivalent Strawberry?  There's no exact equivalent, you should get the highest 5.10.0.X and then fill in missing modules.

Comment: @Schwern: I realised that I'm running Camelbox Perl 5.10.0, but figured that the fourth number in Strawberry Perl was a version of the Perl interpreter, so I'd like to find out which one Camelbox Perl 5.10.0 is using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There won't be a Camelbox which exactly matches Strawberry.  5.10.0.6 is the seventh (starts at 0) Strawberry release of 5.10.0.  Strawberry 5.10.0.6 and Camelbox 5.10.0 should be the same, although they will have different bug fixes and ship with different modules.  You'll have to compile Gtk2 for Strawberry, [here's a discussion on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322493/installing-gtk2-on-portable-strawberry).

If possible you should upgrade to 5.10.1 at least.  It contains a great number of bug fixes as well as [incompatible changes to the smart match operator (`~~`)](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.1/perldelta.html#Incompatible-Changes).  Unfortunately, I see Camelbox hasn't upgraded. :-/

Comment: I've been trying to get the Camelbox Gtk2 libs to work for Strawberry Perl. That discussion is barely a discussion and ends in "if you get a good solution ... publish it". Is the last number of the Strawberry release not a perl version number?

Comment: The last number is the release of Strawberry for that version of Perl.  Perl uses just X.Y.Z.  As far as getting Gtk2 to compile on Strawberry, I don't have anything more to offer on that.  You might want to ask that as a separate question.